# How to generalize a function call which may be async, tornado coroutine, or normal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I have an application which has a library in multiple configurations:

- Python2.7 native
- Python2.7 tornado
- Python3.5 asyncio

Currently, I have code that is nearly identical against all three, but there are minor differences in how each function call are invoked. This means I have a ton of code duplication, because I have stuff like the following in many places:

```
#Python2.7native.py
def main(client):
   client.foo(args)
   client.bar(args)

#Python2.7tornado.py
@gen.coroutine
def main(client):
    yield client.foo(args)
    yield client.bar(args)

#Python3.5asyncio.py
async def main(client):
    await client.foo(args)
    await client.bar(args)
```

where `client` is a language specific implementation, supporting native python, asyncio, and tornado respectively. The API method calls are identical.

I am hoping to be able to somehow generalize this into a single method I can include in a shared file, which appropriately calls the various methods

I've thought about defining the methods in a separate file and using `getattr` to invoke the test properly, but this seems really messy.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: If in fact they are identical in various sections except for how they're called, could you create a list of functions then have the platform-specific runner iterate through that list and call it accordingly?

Comment: The issue is going to be ``async def``.  As far as I know, there's no 2.7 equivalent. If you need to share between multiple version of Python, then I'd opt for ``gen.coroutine`` for those functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do all of this in one function - how is `client.foo()` supposed to know whether it's being called from a "normal" synchronous application, or whether its caller is going to use `yield` or `await`. However, as long as you're willing to have Tornado as a dependency, you can avoid duplicating all your code three times.

In one module, `client_async.py`, implement your function(s) using Tornado's `@gen.coroutine`:

```
@gen.coroutine
def foo(args):
    yield something()
    yield something_else()
    raise gen.Return(another_thing())
```

In another, `client_sync.py`, wrap each of the functions from `client_async.py` in `IOLoop.run_sync()` for a thread-local IOLoop like this:

```
import client_async
import threading
import tornado.ioloop

class _LocalIOLoop(threading.local):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop()
local_ioloop = _LocalIOLoop()

def foo(args):
    return local_ioloop.value.run_sync(lambda: foo_async.my_func(args))
```

Now you can use this code from all three environments. From normal synchronous code:

```
import client_sync

def main():
    x = client_sync.foo(args)
```

From Tornado `@gen.coroutine`:

```
import client_async

@gen.coroutine
def main():
    x = yield client_async.foo(args)
```

From `async def` and `asyncio` (note that the two are not synonymous - it is possible to use `async def` with Tornado without `asyncio`):

```
# one-time initialization for Tornado/asyncio integration
import tornado.platform.asyncio
tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop().install()

import client_async

async def main():
    x = await client_async.foo(args)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `@gen.coroutine` and `yield`: This will work in all Python versions. A function decorated with `gen.coroutine` is a little slower than a native coroutine, but can be used in all the same scenarios.

For the synchronous case, use `run_sync`:

```
result = IOLoop.current().run_sync(main)
```

Comment: How does this answer my question? I need to support asyncio, tornado, and normal python implementations.